# How I can I configure the Google Chat web app so that I continue to recieve notifications on my phone?

Tags: google-chat

How can I configure the Google Chat web app so that notifications continue to show up on my phone whilst I also have the web app open in a browser window, which also (optionally if configured to) provides notifications?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to clarify if you want to enable notifications *simultaneously* in the web app and on mobile or if you are simply trying to ensure that opening the web app doesn't cause notifications to stop on your mobile device?

Comment: I took a crack at editing the question in that fashion, I am not sure exactly how best to suss out the difference between these two as I (personally) want and have the web app providing notifications (when notifications are turned off) of showing notification on the gmail tab it is open in.  There is a further "provide notification" option I do not like or want, where they are popped up as modal on the bottom.  Either way, unless you use custom stasues (or perhaps another path I am unaware of exists) you won't get notifications passed to phone if tab is active in a browser window.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your status from automatic → any custom status in chat sidebar portion of gmail, you will get notifications on your Android device even when Chat is open in an active Chrome session.  This is location where you should enter the custom status (Add a status)

[image]

Comment: Your answer is being auto-flagged by the community bot as low quality because of its brevity. From a human perspective it lacks details.  Please [edit] to improve it so it is useful to the average user.